# Charting in Qt on Linux

Tags: application-development, qt

I want to get into porting Windows apps to Linux but have a few questions about Qt as a possible solution. I have seen Qt touted as an equivalent for VC++ on Linux.
VC++ on Windows has no charting components - one uses 3rd party sw.
I see indications that Qt has charting capabilities but

1. are these placeable on the equivalent of an MFC dialog box?
2. does one require the equivalent if an MFC Picture Control to contain graphs?
3. can one use third party sw for doing 1 and 2 - ie not using any intrinsic Qt charting?

Comment: Have you checked out the Qt Charts overview [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-overview.html)?

Comment: am souring on QT as a solution to getting GUI and charting tasks i have iin windows.  apparently QT is not C++ and according to many posts has performance issues such as taking a long time to actually start executing after an app's launch.  am looking for GUI functionality suboordinate to a master c++ exe.  ie some equivalent of VC++ for unix.

Comment: I'd suggest reading about what Qt is by starting at their [website](https://www.qt.io/).